# Hyperlink Using Full File Path for Internal Reference in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, hyperlink

I am working in an Excel file and trying to link a table of contents to other cells on the sheet – easy enough. The issue I am coming across is that all of the hyperlinks that I put into this document are giving a FULL file path and making it impossible for other users of this file to get access to. When I hover over the link it shows the following:

> file:///C:\Users\Username....etc

My goal: I want these internal links to be local to the document we are working in so that when other users click on it, they won’t error out due to path issues

Ex: When I hover over the link, I want it to read:

> File Name - Sheet1!A1

Not sure if this makes a difference, but my original file is located on a shared Box drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the links, are you using this dialog:

[image: Existing File or Web Page]
?

If so, try clicking on “Place in this Document” button
in the “Link to” column (on the left):

[image: Place in this Document]

Comment: Thanks, Scott - I am using the "Place in This Document" hyperlink.

Comment: Well, that’s peculiar.  When I (1) create a “Place in this Document” hyperlink, (2) save the file (and close it), (3) rename the file, and (4) open it (using the new name), (4a) if I hover over the hyperlink, it shows the new file name, and (4b) if I click on the hyperlink, it just goes to the linked-to cell in the currently open workbook; it doesn’t try to access the original name.  (This works even if I move the file to a different directory.)  Can you think of anything that you’re doing that’s different from what I described?  P.S.  I am using Excel 2013.